# Как поставить действие когда остановиться RecyclerView?

Tags: android

Делаю автоскролл до определенной позиции, как сделать действие, чтобы оно срабатывало как только он остановиться:

```
((RecyclerView) findViewById(list[finalI-1])).smoothScrollToPosition(finalRandomStandart);
```

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте листенер:

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
       switch (newState) {
           case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
               //we reached the target position
               recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
               break;
       }
   }
```

};